# Accessing element index in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to save the index of an element in a matrix as following

```py
cx = []
for j in range(len(self.correctors_indexes)):
    self.lattice[self.correctors_indexes[j]].KickAngle = [self.dkick, 0.00]

    lindata0, tune, chrom, lindata = self.lattice.linopt(get_chrom=True, refpts=self.BPM_indexes)    
    closed_orbitx = lindata['closed_orbit'][:, 0]
    cx.append(closed_orbitx)

    [row, col] = cx.index(str(closed_orbitx))
    file = open("orm_x_CXY_"+ [row, col] +".txt", "w")
    str1 = repr(self.lattice[self.correctors_indexes[j]].KickAngle)
    file.write(str1)
    file.close()

    Cx = np.squeeze(cx) / self.dkick
    return Cx
```

But i received the error

```
cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Instead i tried to add the function "find":

```py
def find(element, matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j] == element:
                return (i, j)
```

And i used it as following:

```py
[row, col] = find(closed_orbitx , cx)
file = open("orm_x_CXY_"+ [row, col] +".txt", "w")
```

But i got the error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can i extract the element index in a matrix and use in in the files names?

Comment: Could you share the full error trace or at least indicate which line is triggering the error? That would help a lot to answer. Also please share the full function because you have a return outside a def for the first code, it is a bit hard to understand. Finally when need to access an element in a iterable `elements` and use its indice, it is easier to use `for j, element in enumerate(elements)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the function [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to get the indices of a value within an array or a matrix and later use these values for a filename. See the following example:

```py
element = 4
mat = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5], 
    [6, 7, 8],
])

idxs = np.argwhere(mat == element)

print(idxs[0])  # --> [1, 1]

# Unpack the row and column index
row, col = idxs[0]

# You can then use the pair in a filename like
fname = f"file_{row}-{col}.txt"

# or similarly
fname = "file_{}-{}.txt".format(row, col)
```

Note however that `np.argwhere` *always* returns an array of indices.

Comment: It *may* be the case that idxs has more than 1 entry on the first index, but that depends on your inputs. If you can be sure that the value is always unique, then the first dimension in the output of argwhere will always have the length 1.